# My game works on the simulator, why doesn't it work on a physical phone?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

[The game HUD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSlIX.png) I am making a game in Unity 2D with C#. It is similar to Hill Climb Racing. The game has four buttons.The red button is brake, the green button is gas, the arrow button restarts the level, and the bomb button throws a bomb. For the gas and brake buttons, I use OnMouseDown to set a "pressed" boolean to true, and OnMouseUp to set it back to false. While the "pressed" boolean is true, the following code activates:

```
car.AddForce(transform.right * 0.01f, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
car.AddTorque(0.2f);
```

The opposite activates for the brake button.
The bomb and restart button simply use OnMouseDown and immediately carry out their function.

All buttons work perfectly in Unity itself and in its simulator. However, when I build it to Xcode and run it on my physical phone, the gas and brake buttons do not work correctly. The bomb button and the restart button work perfectly though. However, when the gas and brake buttons are pressed, the particle effect activates. This is dependent on the car's velocity, however. This is strange because both the snowEffect and the reverseSnowEffect are playing at the same time when either button is pressed. The car does not visibly move, however.

```
if(car.velocity.x > 0){
snowEffect.Emit(1);
} else if(car.velocity.x < 0) {
reverseSnowEffect.Emit(1);
}
```

Comment: When you use the simulator in Unity, try to test it with the exact same configuration your phone has. This goes beyond just the phone's model, look into the exact OS version in the settings as well